# A bug where the DOM disappears on iPhone Safari. (nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, vue.js, nuxt.js

It is a web developed as nuxt.js. (nuxt: ^ 1.0.0-alpha.3)

The website in question is here.

http://fduroot.com/board/list?kind=job

Try connecting to that address on iPhone Safari.

[image]

**It is not displayed as above.**

---

[image]

**Displayed when connected with Chrome.**

---

[image]

**other pages are displayed.**

---

[image]
[image]

**Why is DOM disappearing?**

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: not see console errors.

Comment: Working for me now (iOS 11). OP must have fixed it.

Comment: Do not you see the page? The problem is serious.